# How can I auto-add to my contacts people who send me email in Outlook?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2016

### Premise

I use outlook at work and while there's an auto-suggest feature for people who *I* have sent emails to - already handy - and I have a corporate addressbook, there are some annoying limitations.

Important tidbit: I'm using Outlook 2016 for macOs.

### Issues

For starters, and most importantly, when sync-ed to my phone (Android), only my own outlook contacts are sync-ed (not my corporate address book).

So:

- How could I *auto-add* people who send me emails to my address book?
- If not auto-add, could I do a bulk import? (right click -> Sender -> add to address book only works when selecting a single message)

### Bonus Points

Yes, I know this means this will auto-add every spammer. I don't care. That worked fine for my Google Contacts for years, and I never really cared.

Still, bonus points if you an define a rule to say "auto-add every users who send me an email from `[list of domains here]`.

### Constraints

All solutions welcome. A built-in outlook solution would be best, but I couldn't find one. A plug-in is OK. A background script or daemon is OK. A macro is OK. Whatever you can find that works is worthy of interest.

Comment: I suggest writting a add-on to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound: can we even write Add-Ins for Outlook for macOS? I don't think so, but I'm not very familiar with either the Office landscape and the Office for Mac landscape. All the links and online questions when I want to check for this sent me to this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Add-Ins-for-Office-2016-for-Mac-f33bd0af-3d2b-4c00-8c2e-45e2aa96cb9a . Which covers only Excel and Word Add-Ins (and quite briefly...)

Comment: You indicated that, "A plug-in is OK.", now your saying that you don't believe an add-on solution is not possible?  I am confused.  Anyways, yes add-ons do not exist on OS X.  Which means you would have to use a script or daemon to do this.

Comment: @Ramhound: I was just saying that any kind of solution is OK, and I also said I am on Outlook for macOS. I don't know what works and what does not. I'm just open to suggestions. I value yours, and I ask a follow-up to check its feasibility. That's all.